# Minimize code size to avoid duplication of the same code

Tags: php, html

I need one advice from you. I am working on a website, which uses PHP and HTML. As the biggest part of the header and footer code will be same for many pages, I am thinking of using PHP's include to avoid code duplication. But, each of those pages requires different stylesheets and JS files included. What do you think how could I let the other file know what scripts and stylesheet to import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I do:

```
<?php include("includes/headContent.php"); ?>
<title>Page title goes here!</title>
<script src="script_only_used_on_this_page"></script>
<?php
    require_once("includes/siteHeader.php");
?>
Site Content Goes Here!!
<?php
    require_once("includes/siteFooter.php");
?>
```

Head Content includes any PHP I want included in every page, as well as the opening html and head tag, and any Javascript libraries and css stylesheets I want on every page. Site header closes the /head tag, and opens the body as well as printing out my site header and some other markup that goes on every page. Finally Site Footer closes out my template. Everything in between is my content area!

Comment: I was thinking of that too. I think I will stick to that then. :)

Answer (score 1):

Our company does this:

The header reads the filename of the page calling it when it's included.
Then, it changes the extension to '.js' and outputs that if it exists. Same for CSS.

So if I have a page "register.php", it will auto-include "register.js" and "register.css" if they exist.

Comment: That will make lots of duplicated code in the end. Most of the style is the same for all pages.

Comment: So include both the default CSS and the page-specific CSS. We include 3 layers.. Page, Area, and Global CSS/JS.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different ways you can do templating, if you wanted to create a simple include and an echoHeader() and an echoFooter() function... just have the echoHeader function accept a parameter which you would pass your javascript and CSS lines to.

Comment: Not really that I wanted to use a function for this. Just a plain PHP file, which would generate output without calling any functions. I was thinking of just declaring a variable, because I would be able to access it in the included file also. What do you think?

Comment: I would have a separate PHP file called like... _functions.php and inside the 2 functions, one that accepts parameters for the CSS and JS... and then in your files you don't want to repeat code in, include('_functions.php'); echoHeader('<script type etc...'); put content, then echoFooter();

Answer (score 0):

you can use MVC coding pattern

Comment: I could give that a try. But I rather want to use something that suits me more than MVC.